# Windows Installer - Another version of this product already exists

Tags: c#, installshield-le

I've asked this question already and can't believe that no one has an answer and I write it again in a different way to see if anyone can lend a hand.

When I create the second version of my winforms app and configure InstallSheild LE to install it, all seems to be straightforward.

When I then run the install I go through a couple of screens and then a popup appears stating:

"Another version of this product exists....Use Add/Remove programs on control panel"

Can anyone confirm if the LE version of InstallShield that is freely available for VS2012 will create an update installation that doesn't require the removal of the current version, or do I need a paid for version to get this basic functionality?

Thanks,

Jason.

Comment: @PhoenixReborn - Great work detective. You found the question he said he made. Jason, take a look at the answer to this question: [Update an existing installation using InstallShielf LE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337860/update-an-existing-installation-using-installshield-le)

Comment: @Logarr - And you point would be what? Are you saying that because it already exist that is it somehow not a duplicate posting?

Comment: @PhoenixReborn - My point is that he already stated it was a re-write of another question that he himself posted. Pointing to it and calling it a duplicate is not constructive; especially considering that there were no comments or answers on the original.

Comment: @Logarr - and again so? Just because he said that he already asked does not make it not a duplicate. In fact, encouraging him to post the same question over and over is even less constructive. That is exactly why the poster have the ability to _edit_ their posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the PackageCode and the ProductCode to make the installer think it's a completely new install.

I'm not sure where that will be in InstallShield (I don't use it).