# Dynamically change Upgrade Code in Install Shield

Tags: msbuild, installation, teamcity, installshield, installshield-le

As said [here](http://syncor.blogspot.com/2013/03/doing-upgrades-with-installshield-le.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337860/update-an-existing-installation-using-installshield-le), doing an upgrade with Install Shield is easy.
Did it, but I need something more - I need to change the Upgrade Code, **of an upgrade**, dynamically.
I have TeamCity, which builds my product with different Upgrade codes - this way I have different products, that I can install on same machine. I am doing it using *InstallShieldPropertyOverrides* in **.isproj* file. It works, but I want every single of those products to be upgradeable, so I need to change the Upgrade Code in Upgrades section (Orginize Your Setup > Upgrade Paths). I need it to be done dynamically, during build on TeamCity, but I found no InstallShield property in *InstallShieldPropertyOverrides* to be configured with MSBuild. Does anyone have an idea or solution?

Comment: Matching UpgradeCode doesn't prevent side-by-side installations, only ProductCode does that. Could you edit your question clarify what scenarios you are trying to support (perhaps provide a couple examples)? Note that the limited edition may not be well suited towards the level of configuration you desire.

Comment: No experience with .isproj files, but the ISWiProject script object (http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm) can be used to set the upgradecode (or productcode as Michael says)

Comment: I need to set the upgrade code in Orginize Your Setup > Upgrade Paths section. Would it be that method: AddAutomaticUpgradeEntry? Can I use it with IS Limited Edition?