# Running updated MSI does not have any effect

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield

I created MSI using InstallShield and installed a package.
Next step I created an update. On the property page of MSI file I had to setup the same "Revision number" as in the original one because otherwise I get message:

*Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure ore remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel*

But once I double click on new MSI the system actually runs an old one saved in c:\windows\installer. Is there anyway to force the system to run the new MSI file? (I changed the version number, but kept all other UIDs the same)

BTW when I delete "LocalPackage" entry in registry then the system runs new MSI.

---

Now I tried to create new installation. I changed major version and also Product version. I get error:

*A newer version of this application is already installed on this computer. If you wish to install this version, please uninstall the newer version first.*

Comment: This one solved the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337860/update-an-existing-installation-using-installshield-lecopy guid from /General info/"product code" to /Upgrade PAth / Upgrade code
copy guid from /General info/"product code" to /General info / Upgrade code
pres button "..." in /General info/product code to generate new guid
Optional settings. In /Upgrade PAth / Upgrade code
disable max version
enable min version, for example you can put version 0.0.0.1 for minimal.
disable languale dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that defines whether a product is installed is the ProductCode. The revision number of an MSI file is more commonly known as the PackageCode. Both the PaCckageCode and the ProductCode must be different for creating a major upgrade.

I wouldn't advise deleting the local package MSI. That's used for maintenance and uninstalls.

Comment: It's also important to look at the Upgrade table to see if the MSI supports same-version upgrades. If not, you'll also need to update the ProductVersion "x.y.z".

Comment: If I do that the package is installed but in Program and Features two packages will appear under the same name.

Comment: That means you're nearly there, except that you probably haven't got the major upgrade configured correctly. Either that or the original is per user and the new one is per machine (or vice versa)/