# Forceful upgrade with InstallShield 2013 LE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, installshield, windows-installer

I have a WPF application which I develop. Its Setup is InstallShield 2013 LE project.

A clean install is fine. However, when I REBUILD my setup and run it again, it shows error "Another version of this product is already installed".

What I want is when I run Setup again, installation is FORCED with no regard to what version (might be) already installed.

P.S. Upgrade paths were suggested, but don't seem to affect the setup behavior. The setup version isn't changed between rebuilds, it's all the way 1.0.0, the same product and upgrade code.

The whole idea is to reinstall and reinstall, until development is done, just like in continous integration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuring InstallShield LE to remove previous versions built using Visual Studio Setup Projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447404/configuring-installshield-le-to-remove-previous-versions-built-using-visual-stud)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run

```
msiexec /fva Mixed.Studio.msi
```

prior to running actual setup of the product. The code above runs smoothly with no regard to is the product installed or not.

The code forcefully replaces stored MSI with the new one, which takes away "Another version..." message. More than that, even if the user cancels setup, it still can later do "Restore" from Control Panel, and by doing that new version will effectively be installed.