# Can't find RemovePreviousVersions property in MSI setup

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

I am building a MSI setup with Visual Studio 2012.
I would like that the previous version of my installer will be delected when a newer one is started.

In various documentation i found that the property RemovePreviousVersions has to be setted to true in order to do that (as well as updating the ProductCode).

My problem is quite silly but i can't find this attribute in the properties.
Could someone just tell me the path?

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question.
That property does not exist anymore.
In order to upgrade version I found another solution.... here it is the link:

[Configuring InstallShield LE to remove previous versions built using Visual Studio Setup Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447404/configuring-installshield-le-to-remove-previous-versions-built-using-visual-stud)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you were looking at documentation of RemovePreviousVersions in the context of Visual Studio Installer projects (NOT InstallShield LE projects). If you use Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 (and Community Editions are free) you can install the installer extension which DO use RemovePreviousVersions:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9