# InstallShield Visual Studio Remove previous version

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield-le

I'm attempting to update a current windows form project through installshield. I'm following the steps to the second answer on this question: [Configuring InstallShield LE to remove previous versions built using Visual Studio Setup Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447404/configuring-installshield-le-to-remove-previous-versions-built-using-visual-stud/16222280#16222280)

However I'm hitting a snag: When I add an update path, it brings up a file dialog, and I can't locate the MSI file. I have the setup.exe stored on a shared drive.

I'm a little lost. I apparently cannot build my install project if I create a new Upgrade Path and cancel out of the dialog.

Comment: All it really needs is the MSI's upgrade code. Can you get that, and does LE let you type it in? If not, can you extract the MSI from the EXE (or install it and grab a cached copy), and browse to that?

Comment: I couldn't find the MSI at all, but I resolved it.... don't remember how, though. I think I might have used my solution's file path. It works now, though